# how to make the nuxt child component wait until asyncData call get finish

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex-orm

For a form we have 2 components parent(for calling asyncdata and pass data as props to child) & child(form). I can properly fetch the props in child if I navigate using a link. But If I try to refresh the child component page it throws error as no props is passed. Found the reason to be that the parents asyncdata is not completing before the child render to sent the data in props.

> Parent Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>EDIT</p>
    <NewListingModal :is-edit="true" :form-props="this.form" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import NewListingModal from '@/components/NewListingModal.vue'

  export default {
    components: { NewListingModal },
    async asyncData({ params, store }) {
      const listing = await store.$db().model('listings').find(params.listing)  //vuexorm call
      if (typeof listing !== 'undefined') {
        const convertedListing = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listing))
        return {
          name: '',
          scrollable: true,
          form: {names: convertedListing.names}
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

> child component(other form data is removed to keep it understandable)

```
<template>
  <div v-for="name in this.form.names" :key="name">
    <p>{{ name }} <a @click.prevent="deleteName(name)">Delete<a /></a></p>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
  import Listing from '@/models/listing'


  export default {
    name: 'ListingModal',
    props: {isEdit: {type: Boolean, default: false}, formProps: {type: Object}},
    data() {
      return {
        name: '',
        scrollable: true,
        form: {names: this.formProps.names}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addName() {
        this.form.names.push(this.name)
        this.name = ''
      },
      deleteName(name) {
        const names = this.form.names
        names.splice(names.indexOf(name), 1)
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

How can I make the `NewListingModal` component rendering wait until the asyncData completes in parent?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used `asyncData` in my parent nuxt component, which fetches the data via store `dispatch` action, then set it to some store state key, via mutation.

Then I used `validate` method in my child component. Since Nuxt `validate` can return promises, I checked the vuex store first for fetched data. If there is none, I refetch it and return the promise instead.

In Parent component.vue

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, store }) {
       // Api operation which may take sometime
       const {data} = await store.dispatch('fetch-my-data')
       store.commit('setData', data) //This should be within above dispatch, but here for relevance 
  }
}
```

Here I am only fetching and saving to vuex store.

Child component.vue

```js
export default {
   async validate({ params, store }) {
      let somedata = store.state.data //This is what you've set via parent's component mutation
      return !!somedata || store.dispatch('fetch-my-data')
   }
}
```

Here I am returning either the vuex store data (if exists), else refetch it.